# Correct way to host SPA using S3, Cloudfront and Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I built a react app and am trying out different hosting services. Using an s3 bucket to store files then using cloud front distribution seems solid so I'm trying it out.

I built my React app and added this script to package.json

```
aws s3 sync build/ s3://<bucket-name>
```

Then I created a distribution network using the bucket name endpoint that was listed under s3 properties and that status now says deployed.

Now I have a domain name that I purchased on Godaddy. I changed the nameserver's to the 4 provided by AWS Route53 in the Hosted Zone. This also created 2 record sets. I then added a 3rd record set, ALIAS and the target is the cloudfront.net url.

Now I'm seeing two different results.

On safari browser, Safari throws a 403 Error. 
On chrome I get a message saying "Your connection is not private" even though I can view the valid cloudfront certificates in the url bar.

I have bucket policy on my s3 that looks like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
          "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Was there something I missed?

Comment: Everything works fine when you use cloudfront's url, instead of R53?

Comment: yup. the cloud front url is this: d13r42lbfv3bz6.cloudfront.net . I entered that as the Alias value for A record and am still getting failed to open page on custom domain.

Comment: Seems fine. Maybe its on godaddy side problem. Maybe have to flush some dns cache or wait til TTL expires?

Comment: ya it hasn't been 48 hours like they say it can sometimes take, but usually when done right it only ever really takes like up to an hr right? lol

Comment: Its seems too long. Don't have more ideas for now. The obvious question, have you reset cache in your browsers?

Comment: I have. I use Macpaw's CleanMyMac which does a dns flush. Haven't made any improvement just getting a 403 error now, but my bucket policy should be solving any 403 errors and if I'm not getting that error on cloudfront.net url why would I on custom domain..